# Remove last comma from string with line breaks

Tags: php

I create a string with line breaks from other strings using a `foreach` loop and depending on the numbers given in a variable I concatenate the strings. like this:

```
$Medio=''; //variable to handle the result

$MedioPago='12345'; //variable with numbers given

$chars = str_split($MedioPago); //split the numbers


foreach($chars as $char)
{
    if($char=='1')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "01",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='2')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "02",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='3')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "03",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='4')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "04",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='5')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "05",'.PHP_EOL;
    }   
}

$Medio = rtrim($Medio,',');
```

The problem I have is that, since the resulting string has line breaks, `rtrim` does not remove the last comma.

How can I remove last comma from the resulting string?

Comment: You could `rtrim()` the last line break too.

Comment: @AlexHowansky this is it, I didn't thought about removing last line break before removing the last comma.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I ended up doing: I just added `$Medio = rtrim($Medio,','.PHP_EOL)` to remove last line break before removing the last comma as Alex Howansky pointed out.

```
$Medio=''; //variable to handle the result

$MedioPago='12345'; //variable with numbers given

$chars = str_split($MedioPago); //split the numbers


foreach($chars as $char)
{
    if($char=='1')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "01",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='2')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "02",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='3')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "03",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='4')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "04",'.PHP_EOL;
    }
    else if($char=='5')
    {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "05",'.PHP_EOL;
    }   
}

$Medio = rtrim($Medio,','.PHP_EOL);
```

Comment: Note you don't need two calls to `rtrim()` -- the second parameter can contain multiple characters to trim.

Comment: @AlexHowanskyHow can I add `PHP_EOL` to `rtrim()`?

Comment: `rtrim($str, ",\n")` or `rtrim($str, ',' . PHP_EOL)`

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you're building a comma separated string, I find it best to make an array containing the elements and then use `implode()` to join them. This will avoid the necessity to remove the last comma, or any extraneous code to track which iteration you're on. Also, any time you have repetitive if/else statements like this, try to find what's similar between them and use a loop instead:

```
$list = [];
foreach (str_split($MedioPago) as $char) {
    $list[] = sprintf('"codigo": "%02d"', $char);
}
$Medio = implode(",\n", $list);
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `substr`

```
$newString = substr($Medio, 0, -3);
```

Comment: Won't this just remove the line break and not the comma as well (also PHP_EOL may be 2 characters)

Comment: Yes it would, I just didnt have PHP_EOL when i tested in my machine. so in the case of the OP he would have to use ```substr($Medio, 0, -3);```

Answer (score 1):

The logic I like to use for scenarios like this is to conditionally print the comma plus EOL *before* each appended term, but only if that term is *not* the first one being added:

```
$Medio = NULL;
$MedioPago = '12345';
$chars = str_split($MedioPago);

foreach ($chars as $char) {
    if ($Medio != NULL) {
        $Medio.=','.PHP_EOL;
    }

    if ($char == '1') {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "01"';
    }
    else if ($char == '2') {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "02"';
    }
    else if ($char == '3') {
       $Medio.='"codigo": "03"';
    }
    else if ($char == '4') {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "04"';
    }
    else if ($char == '5') {
        $Medio.='"codigo": "05"';
    }   
}
```

PHP might have a string trimming function which could work here, but the above approach works by avoiding ever adding an unwanted stray comma plus EOL in the first place.